# Troubleshooting arc fault breaker

Tags: electrical

My arc fault has tripped the circuit affects two bed rooms I unplugged everything in both bed rooms the arc fault will not reset. I pulled all receptical and switches in both rooms checking for loose wires and any bare wires. Breakers still does not reset I replace with a new arc fault breaker the problem still exists I also Putin a standard breaker and both the bedrooms are powered I,m still trying find out what and where the problem is any recommendations

Comment: What make/model of AFCI is this?

Comment: Did you replace it with a GFCI, or a normal breaker? It may be an earth fault - earth and neutral shorted somewhere, or a load connected to earth rather than neutral.

Comment: The arc fault breaker is a Eaton 15 amp arcing

Comment: Can you put the arc fault breaker back in and extract the diagnostic codes from it?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have removed the loads and replaced the breaker there could be a pinched or skined wire in this circuit causing the fault. A megger to verify the insulation is good is the quickest way I know. The wires are removed from the breaker and all switches off. If there is a low resistance at less than 500v there is usually a staple or nail through the insulation. If the test is good start turning on switches, lamps/ bulbs out when one circuit shows a low value this is the one to check. With all this said if you have recently added flouresent lighting, a large computer / UPS or a large dimmer on any kind of lighting circuit arc fault breakers can't tell the difference from an arc and a electronic load and will trip.